# AccessViolationException when accessing the Above, Below, Suffix, and Prefix properties of a Dimension

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

In Revit 2013 I have tool that I'm making that copies dimensions from one drafting view to another.  I've got it to properly create a new version of a dimension including the `Curve`, `DimensionType`, and `References` but I'm having trouble with the properties `Above`, `Below`, `Prefix`, and `Suffix`.  They copy just fine if at least one of them has a value.  However, if none of them have a value then it will throw an `AccessViolationException` when I try to access them.  I have tried to catch that exception but it bubbles up and it crashes Revit (I'm assuming it's caused by native code that fails).

How can I check to see if these properties have any value when I do my copying without triggering this `AccessViolationException`?

[Autodesk Discussion Group Question](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-Revit-API/AccessViolationException-on-Above-Below-Prefix-and-Suffix-for/m-p/3765595)

The `DimensionData` class is my own used for storing the dimension information so that it can be used to create the dimension in a separate document.

```
private IEnumerable<DimensionData> GetDimensionDataSet(Document document, 
  View view)
{
  if (document == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("document");

  if (view == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("view");

  List<DimensionData> dimensionDataSet = new List<DimensionData>();

  FilteredElementCollector dimensionCollector = 
    new FilteredElementCollector(document, view.Id);

  dimensionCollector.OfClass(typeof(Dimension));

  foreach (Dimension oldDimension in dimensionCollector)
  {
    Line oldDimensionLine = (Line)oldDimension.Curve;
    string dimensionTypeName = oldDimension.DimensionType.Name;

    List<ElementId> oldReferences = new List<ElementId>();

    foreach (Reference oldReference in oldDimension.References)
      oldReferences.Add(oldReference.ElementId);

    DimensionData dimensionData;

    try
    {
      string prefix = oldDimension.Prefix;

      dimensionData = new DimensionData(oldDimensionLine,
                                        oldReferences,
                                        dimensionTypeName,
                                        prefix,
                                        oldDimension.Suffix,
                                        oldDimension.Above,
                                        oldDimension.Below);
    }
    catch (AccessViolationException)
    {
      dimensionData = new DimensionData(oldDimensionLine, 
        oldReferences, dimensionTypeName);
    }

    dimensionDataSet.Add(dimensionData);
  }

  return dimensionDataSet;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark - but I recall certain pieces of code in the API that don't behave right unless there's an open transaction. Do you have an open transaction when you're doing the code you're showing above?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding transactions:  As far as I'm aware, you are only required to be inside a transaction when you are making any sort of CHANGE (modifications, deletions, additions).  If all you are doing is collecting dimension information, you would not need a transaction, but when you use that information to create new dimensions in another document, that code would have to be inside a transaction.  I have had a number of programs under development which did not yet modify the document but simply collected parameter settings and posted them to a TaskDialog.Show().  These programs worked fine, and I don't see anything in your code that actually modifies your model, so that doesn't seem to be your issue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like I bug.
Can you post the issue to the ADN Support?

The solution I can suggest is to use `Parameters` of the `Dimension element` instead of `Dimension` class properties.

For example, you can get `Suffix` and `Prefix` by following code

```
var suffixParameter =
    oldDimension.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SPOT_SLOPE_SUFFIX);
string suffix = null;
if (suffixParameter != null)
{
    suffix = suffixParameter.AsString();
}

var prefixParameter =
    oldDimension.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SPOT_SLOPE_PREFIX);
string prefix = null;
if (prefixParameter != null)
{
    prefix = prefixParameter.AsString();
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I don't tell you how to get `Above` and `Below` Properties via parameters, because I don't have a project to test. But you can easily determine parameters using [BuiltInParameter Checker](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/built-in-parameter-enumeration-duplicates-and-bipchecker-update.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `BuiltInParameter.SPOT_SLOPE_PREFIX` and `BuiltInParameter.SPOT_SLOPE_SUFFIX` parameters do not correspond to `Prefix` and `Suffix` on the `Dimension` so this will not work.  I tried retrieving them using `get_Parameter` but it returned null even though `Prefix` and `Suffix` returned values.  Using the BuiltInParameter Checker also did not work because these 4 properties do not show up as parameters.  :(

Comment: Our ADN subscription has expired so we cannot submit an ADN support ticket.

Comment: Its a bit strange. Before post my suggestion I've checked my code on my test project. If you share your project I will try to help you.

Comment: Do you want my Revit project or my Visual Studio project?  I've checked the `BuiltInParameter.SPOT_SLOPE_PREFIX` and `BuiltInParameter.SPOT_SLOPE_SUFFIX` and like their names state they apply specifically to Spot Slope Dimensions and not Dimensions in general.

Comment: I got a response from saikat on the Autodesk forums and he asked for a test project and test revit file.  You can download [the .zip file that I posted](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-Revit-API/AccessViolationException-on-Above-Below-Prefix-and-Suffix-for/m-p/3769809#M3597).

Comment: In file you provided the Dimension doesn't have a prefix or a suffix property. I'm not very familiar with dimensions. I'm sure that if dimension has a prefix or suffix property you can get it via parameter. Or maybe only Spot Slope dimension may have prefix or suffix?

Comment: I've tested a dimension with a prefix/suffix/above/below and you cannot get them using a parameter.  I've checked using the lookup tool.  Dimensions other than spot slopes do have suffix/prefix because I can get them with the direct properties.